# Android mockup to implementation obstacle

Tags: android, layout, mockups

I am trying to achieve an implementation looking like [this mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8rMJ.png):

[image]

You can see that the fold in the "paper" (there would be up to 5 folds) requires that the edges at the top become more visible (elongated) when the fold is scrolled to the very top.
For this reason, the indentation of the fold must be realized with transparency, instead of a simple brown triangle with some shadow; this would also imply that the list background be brown, without the yellow paper; the yellow paper would be the background of the certain listview-items (one type of listview-item would contain the fold + indentation). So far, so good, I already got that part.

But then, how do I handle the case of a near-empty list? I want the paper to stretch down to the bottom, but if I do like described, only the cells will paint the paper, leaving brown background where the cells have stopped.

The thing at the bottom will be a SlidingDrawer by the way, but that should not be of any concern.

Can somebody help me, please? Or tell me that this is impossible?